# jQuery - change iframe src based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now, I am trying to change the iframe src value based on what select is picked. I have multiple selects/iframes, so I need something to work for all instances.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="changer">
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</option>
        <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com">Twitter.com</option>
    </select>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="changer">
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</option>
        <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://twitter.com">Twitter.com</option>
    </select>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
display:block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.changer').change(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were changing the `src` attribute of the `select` element rather than the `iframe` element.

Given the HTML, you could use `.next('iframe')` in order to change the source of the adjacent `iframe` element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W24ry/)

```
$('.changer').change(function () {
    $(this).next('iframe').attr('src', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.changer').change(function () {
    $(this).next().attr('src', this.value);
});
```